# Error when I try to connect / create Sqlite db on my Blazor project

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, blazor, .net-standard

I am trying to create / connect to a Sqlite db in my razor project, using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite and EntityFramework.Sqlite nuggets packages.

My code :

```
 public static SqliteConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder;

public static void initialiserDB()
        {
            connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder();
            connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = "dbIntranet.db";

            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

               
            }
        }
```

And I got this error (at connection.Open() line) :

> Unhandled exception rendering component: You need to call
> SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider().  If you are using a bundle package, this
> is done by calling SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init().

I tried multiple nuggets packages but still this issue.

Tried to call `SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider()` or calling `SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init()`, still not working.

I know for Blazor app, a lot of project use contextDB for Sqlite db connection, but this code is way similar to what we do in our companies in C# Windows form projects.

I'm new to Blazor also :/

My project use NET Sandard 2.1

Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: blazor wasm or server ?

Comment: Try this code with both, the issue was the same. The final app is plain to be use on a smartphone so, I guess I will use web assembly for the final project

Comment: It cannot work on WASM, that run in the browser, but it should on server side.

Comment: Ok :/ I will try again tomoraw on a new and clean server side project. But if it's cannot work on WASM, I will have to find something else.
Thanks

Comment: Well, with a new server side project, it's working great, thanks :). But I think I missed something about making a windows / smartphone app using browser, with Blazor.